# Why does the Scala load command not work in the REPL in a Windows 10 command prompt?

Tags: scala

I'm new to Scala and trying to understand the basics.
I'm trying to load a file in the REPL using the following command:

```
scala>load Test.scala
```

I get the following error:

> error: not found: value load

Googling around I found that the following works:

```
scala>lo: Test.scala
```

I'm running the REPL in a Windows 10 command prompt.
Can someone please explain what's going on here?
Thx

Comment: `load` doesn't work but `:load` should. And `lo:` **shouldn't** work but `:lo` should.

Comment: jwvh: typeo on lo:. Thx for response. Why is this the case?

Comment: A leading colon `:` means "this is a REPL command, not a Scala statement." What follows the `:` needs to be enough letters to disambiguate the command. So `:l` won't work because `:line` and `:load` both start with `l`, but `:lo`, `:loa`, and `:load` all mean the same thing.